# "Cut hole" in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to build a reticle for a barcode scanner and need to achieve an effect like this:

[image]

Where there is a square hole of specified dimensions in the center of the view. The purpose of this hole is to expose a View underneath it. In the past, I've been using images but I want to try and recreate this in code so I have more control over its properties.

EDIT: This is what I'm thinking the View hierarchy should be

1. Camera Preview
2. View with hole in it

Where 1 is right below 2

Comment: Where the hole is the camera/scanner ?

Comment: @WillomGfx posted a clarification

Comment: Well just the put the camera view in that spot ? what blocks you from doing so ?

Comment: I want the camera preview to keep showing in the background as the reticle overlay should not be completely opaque

Comment: yes well replace that reticle overlay(the white part) with the camera preview

Comment: I've resolved this by putting a .png background with transparent cuthole shape